# JS navigation only works after all images are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a website that has a sticky/fixed navigation down the left hand side and all content scrolling down the right.

I'm using javascript to link my navigation to divs in within the scrolling content. This works great, except my navigation only works once all the content has loaded, otherwise the navigation sends me to random points in my scrolling content (I think this is because the image content needs to load first to register their correct position).

How can I get my navigation to work on load, without manually setting the size for every image?

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dturu5pf/1)

I'm using unveil.js to load images on scroll which is why my image urls are in data-src attribute.

jQuery unveil http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/

```
<div class="social">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#section1" class="navlink">Section 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#section1" class="navlink">Section 1</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="section1" class="section">
  <a href="#"><img src="#" data-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/White-tailed_deer.jpg" /></a>
 </div>

<div id="section2" class="section">
  <a href="#"><img src="#" data-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/White-tailed_deer.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

/* UNVEIL */

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").unveil();
  });
```

/* Floating Nav */

```
  $(function() {
    var $window = $(window),
      main = $('.main'),
      social = $('.social');

    function floatSocialMenu() {
      if ($window.scrollTop() > main.position().top)
        social.css('position', 'fixed');
      else
        social.css('position', 'absolute');
    }

    $(window).resize(floatSocialMenu);
    $(window).scroll(floatSocialMenu);
  });
```

/* Scroll top button */

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
      } else {
        $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
      }
    });

    $('.scrollup').click(function() {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: 0
      }, 600);
      return false;
    });
```

/* Activate navigation */

```
    $('.navlink').click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - 20
      }, 500);
      return false;
    });

    $(window).scroll(function() {

      var position = $(this).scrollTop();

      $('.section').each(function() {
        var target = $(this).offset().top;
        var id = $(this).attr('id');

        if (position >= target) {
          $('.social > ul > li > a').removeClass('active');
          $('.social > ul > li > a[href=#' + id + ']').addClass('active');
        }
      });
    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: And your javascript?

Comment: @user3821345 Your link doesn't work. Please make a jsfiddle

Comment: Fiddle with the right external resources: https://jsfiddle.net/dturu5pf/1/

Comment: @Hackerman Champion, thank you

Comment: In case your HTML is being generated by the server and said server can store the height of each image along with the source location, your quickest solution would be to add a `style="height: [height]px"` attribute to the img template. If that's not an option, hook onto the `.load()` for each img attribute and re-calculate the scroll based on the last clicked navigation element every time an image finishes, this way you will end up at the correct location.

Comment: @WardD.S. Thanks, however I don't know enough about either of these to implement. My HTML isn't being generated by the server, but would it help to add inline styles for height? (I still want images to resize with the browser window)